# Form submission string concat/modify

Tags: javascript, forms, mootools

So not sure if this is possible but I have a pretty complex form. With multiple levels of processing ie: If you click a radio button 'x' amount options so up in a drop down etc etc.

Well the problem I have is all the form fields need a name, and went I submit the form I'm sending alot of junk. IE Url could be '?meat=3434?fruit=34495?salad=034943' you get the idea. But in the end all I'm looking to is pull the 'salad' value into the url without all the other byproducts. IE: '?salad=034943'

I've tried a few things, pulling all the inputs radios etc out of the form and placing them in a div. The making a form with just a hidden value so I can pull through Mootools (But that made conflicts because I'm using Mootools Form.Validator so then that fails) Then I tired to make two forms, One that would just be all show, then I would pull the value I want into the processing form. Which I thought would work but apparently it still will process both forms.

Any ideas/techniques of how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated! (because I'm losing my mind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable any form field you don't want sent and it won't show up in the URL.

In HTML it's:

```
<INPUT type="text" name="foo" DISABLED>
```

In javascript set `document.forms[...].elements[....].disabled = true`.

If you hide the field with CSS it will still be sent like normal.

Answer (score 0):

the elegant way you do this is mount your GET url to submit by yourself.. 
this way you can send only what you want..
dont send any junk.. you can have problems in the future with a variable that you didnt know you were sending..

you can use this util function of jQuery

```
var params = { width:1680, height:1050 };
var str = jQuery.param(params);

// str is "width=1680&height=1050"
```